# Where to find errors when writing to BigQuery from Dataproc?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm using the BigQuery connector to write a dataset into Bigquery from a Dataproc job. I'm writing using JSON, but sometimes, I get this error :

```java
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error during BigQuery job execution:
{"location":"{tempOutputLocation}",
 "message":"Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors,"
           "giving up. Rows: 3; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for" 
           "more details.",
 "reason":"invalid"}
```

I do understand what this message means, I'm even able to fix it most of the time, but it bothers me not to find the `errors[] collection` they're talking about. This is frustrating since the only way to fix the issue without it is to look at the json generated, take a guess on the error and try fix it. This collection may makes things easier !

I looked into my dataproc bucket but couldn't find any error collection.

Any idea on how to get it would be deeply appreciated !

### Edit : More details on Error

I'm writing to BigQuery like this (classical method) :

```scala
// Prepare Configuration
BigQueryOutputConfiguration.configure(
  conf,
  path,
  schema,
  tempBucket,
  BigQueryFileFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON,
  classOf[TextOutputFormat[_, _]]
)

// Create Json from case class value using Gson and save to BigQuery
output.rdd.map(value => (null, new GsonBuilder()
  .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
  .create()
  .toJsonTree(value)
)).saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(conf)
```

Now sometimes, there is some error in Json values and BigQuery is not happy. For example :

```scala
// With a schema like that
val schema: BigQueryTableSchema = new BigQueryTableSchema().setFields(List(
    new BigQueryTableFieldSchema().setName("field").setType("STRING").setMode("NULLABLE")
).asJava

// Error will be raised if I try to write a Json like :
case class MyClass(field: Double)
val json = new Gson().toJson(MyClass(3.14))
```

Here, my Dataproc job will fail, returning the error mentionned above. Makes sense, since I'm supplying a Double instead of a String. But sometimes it's more tricky, like too many decimals.

Anyway, the Error message clearly mention `Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.` and my hope is that there is somewhere a collection with more details on the mistake that was made than `JSON table encountered too many errors`. But I can't find it.

Comment: Could you let me know what the problem is? I want to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Dagang, I've put some more information on how to reproduce. Please make me know if you need some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced the problem, the `errors` returned by BigQuery API was discarded by BigQuery connector. I filed an [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/issues/237) for BQ connector. We'll fix in the next release.